# How to install zbase62 offline

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I downloaded `zbase62` from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbase62).  I copied the tarball onto my offline linux machine and unzipped it with `tar -xzf` resulting in a folder called `zbase62-1.2.0`.  In the directory containing this folder, I did

```
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=/path/to/zbase/zbase62-1.2.0 zbase62
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting zbase62
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement zbase62
  No distributions at all found for zbase62
```

I've tried several minor variations of this with no success, even though I've had success with other packages.  Is it possible to install zbase62 offline?  Until then I'll have to just modify my path variable.

Answer (score 1):

Running the command as:

```
pip install zbase62
```

Worked for me.  Only when the --no-index was used did I see the same error.

Comment: Is `Sudo` intentionally capitalized?

Comment: Is there some reason you are running it with --no-index?  The only time I got the error you are seeing is when I ran the command with this.  If I ran as pip install zbase62 it install fine.  If I run pip install --no-index zbase62 I get " Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement zbase62
  No distributions at all found for zbase62"

Comment: A key word in the title of my post is 'offline'.  Have you tested your solution on a machine not connected to the internet?  Not sure of the source; someone suggested `--no-index` as a way to make it work offline.

Answer (score 1):

I was also able to install offline with the above steps and using `pip install zbase62` without --no-index

Answer (score 0):

1 - download it (Linux)

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/z/zbase62/zbase62-1.2.0.tar.gz
```

2- extract it (Linux)

```
tar -xvfz zbase62-1.2.0.tar.gz
```

3- then install it (Linux)

```
cd zbase62*;python setup.py install
```

if u use Windows

extract it on disk C:\ then open CMD and
if u use Python V2.7*

```
cd zbase62*;C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install
```

Comment: `python setup.py install` in the inner directory is one of the things I tried that did not work.  Have you tested this with an offline computer?

Comment: what is ur system : Linux or Windows ?